# How to format python string with both double and single quotes

Tags: python

I need to create a python string like:

```
'A' "B"
```

Which I think should be reliably produced using:

```
my_string = "'A' \"B\""
```

What I get here is:

```
'\'A\' "B"'
```

Which inst what we want. Help!

(Why... InfluxDB uses both single and double quotes in queries)

Comment: That is what you want. Don't mind the escapes slashes. See `print(my_string)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string *is* correct the way you wrote it. The output you see is confusing you because you are seeing the "`repr`" (unambiguous) form of the string, presumably because you just typed the variable name at the prompt. Note that this form also adds a pair of (single) quotes around the string, no matter what you put in your variable.

Display the string with `print(my_string)` to see what it really contains.

```
>>> my_string = "Hello, world\n"
>>> my_string
'Hello, world\n'
>>> print(my_string)
Hello, world

>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you get that output in python shell, while entering only the name of the string. You'll get the output you want if you use print(string_name).

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of Python having three types of quotes to eliminate backslashes on entry:

```
>>> my_string = ''''A' "B"'''
>>> my_string
'\'A\' "B"'
>>> print(my_string)
'A' "B"
>>>
```

As you can see, Python is adding backslashes to properly display the string in its interpreter, it's not misunderstanding your input.  Upon `print()` everything comes out as desired.